# How to refresh a page without resetting the filters options selected on dropdown list in a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, reload, restore

On a javascript page how to ***reload/refresh*** a page without resetting its filters selected from the dropdown option selected.

I have put down the code I'm using but its resetting the filter options as well.

`setInterval("location.reload(false)", 300000);` // to refresh page every 5mint

Comment: put all selected item in query string or in local storage. Then retrive via js the value(via query string or local storage) and set for each dropdown.

Comment: Hi , thanks for that ,  but here in my condition I have already selected the filter from the dropdown and every 5 minutes a refresh is done on my page that will remove all the filters that I have selected. Whereas I do not want my filters to reset instead only page refresh should happen.

Comment: in the start up of js code go to read all dropdown value selected so put in query strings or in local storage

Comment: It's not possible to remain the options chosen after a refresh. You should store the filtered state somewhere that will not be reset like url query string or localstorage, and then after every refresh, get those state back and manually set to dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

No way :))
store selected item (or index), select it after relaod